# NBA 2K21 crashes when i play

Tags: technical-issues, epic-games-launcher, nba2k21

I got this game on Epic Games.  Whenever I try to play a game, it loads to 100%, asks me to press A to continue, and when I do, the game closes and opens epic games with no error or crash log.  I have tried verifying the game files, and disabling v-sync on both the game and Nvidia.  (I have not tried disabling overlay yet, not sure where that is on epic games).  How do i fix the crashing?

Edit:

I have a 12 core cpu with 16  gb of ram, along with a geforce gtx 750 ti graphics card, so I believe I should have no problem at the least running the game.  I am not sure if I have avx, which could be the problem, not sure.

Comment: The only thing that can be done is exposure.  I'm guessing a lot of people are gaming with oldish pcs without avx which run perfectly well, and either bought nba 2k21 or got it free on epic games.  If you did, post asking for a patch to fix it!  If enough people do, hopefully 2k will realize we arent that small a number of people, and release a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my pc doesn't have avx, and NBA 2K21 requires avx to play it.  Apparently they assume we all have the latest gaming pc's.  This is ridiculous, and reflects poorly on 2K.  The only way to fix this would be if 2K released a patch so non avx players can play, but considering the fact that this game was released with no cheat prevents, I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: AVX was first introduced in 2011, when even the most powerful CPUs had only 8 cores at most. Which CPU do you have that has 16 cores and still no AVX, if I may ask?

Comment: Actually I said I have 12 cores and 16 *gb of ram* but I was wrong.  I have 12 *logical processors* and 6 physical cores.  Was confused by system configuration.

Comment: I'm personally concerned that a lot of companies will do this, and then old pcs which are completely capable of running such games will be kicked to the curb.  Let's not turn pc gaming into the game of console buying.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You did write you had 12 cores. I must've either misread it, or mixed it up while doing research on AVX. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: no problem, thnx for the help.

Comment: And 2K, every pc player who cant play this game, is a pc player who won't buy your cosmetics.  (end rant)